# Clarifying a step in a real analysis book.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm referring to the short proof in page 41 of this [book](https://measure.axler.net/SupplementMIRA.pdf) that proves the following theorem:

*Suppose $F$ is a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:F\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous. Then $g(F)$ is a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.*

The proof for the $g(F)$ being closed (i.e., it contains the limit of every convergent
sequence of elements of the set) is as follows:

- Suppose $g(a_1),g(a_2),\dots$ is a convergent sequence, where each $a_k\in F$. Let $t=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}g(a_k)$.
- By Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem, some subsequence of $a_1,a_2,\dots$, say $a_{m_1},a_{m_2},\dots$ converges to some $a\in F$.
- Because $g$ is continuous at $a$, this implies that $t=g(a)$. Thus, $t\in g(F)$. By the definition of a closed subset, we get that $g(F)$ is closed.

**What I don't understand:**

Why does the second dot point imply that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}g(a_k)=g(a)$? I thought it should only imply that $\lim_{m_l\rightarrow\infty}g(a_{m_l})=g(a)$? What is the logical step that I'm not seeing. Thanks.

Comment: If a sequence converges, then its limit equals the limit of any subsequence (they are all automatically convergent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t=\lim_{k \to \infty} g(a_k)$ implies that $t=\lim_{l \to \infty} g(a_{m_l})$ also and this last limit is $g(a)$ by continuity of $g$ at $a$.

Comment: The subscript of the second limit is meant to be $m_l\rightarrow\infty$ I presume?

Comment: @Resu Yes, corrected.